# Wrapper .owl-controls is removed in Owl Carousel 2

Tags: owl-carousel

Container .owl-controls around nav and dots don't exist anymore but i need them. Someone an idea how I can restore the wrap around nav and dots?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If someone is looking for... Here my solution to get back the wrap owl-controls around owl-nav and owl-dots...

```
var owlCarousel = $('.owl-carousel');

owlCarousel.owlCarousel({
    items : 1,
    margin: 0,
    rewind: true,
    nav: true,
    autoplay: false,
    autoplayHoverPause: true,
});

// Wrap around nav & dots
owlCarousel.each(function(index) {
    $(this).find('.owl-nav, .owl-dots').wrapAll("<div class='owl-controls'></div>");
});
```

Comment: man this is gold! in case someone customized the content like me, targeting all elements except of stage-outer worked for me: `$(this).children().not('.owl-stage-outer').wrapAll("<div class='owl-controls'></div>");`